# Generate sequence of repeating, ascending integers, using a list containing the number of repetitions for each, with thrust

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, thrust

I would like to generate a sequence of repeating ascending integers, given a list containing the number of repetitions required of each:

```
thrust::device_vector<int> reps {3, 2, 5, 1};
//This vector should yield a resulting list:
// {0,0,0, 1,1, 2,2,2,2,2, 3}
```

Ideally I would like to do this using the thrust API.

I have considered this approach:

1. Prefix sum the reps list to produce a cumulative reps list.
2. Allocate the resulting integer vector using the final element in the cumulative reps list.
3. Using a kernel, run a thread for each element of the reps list, and loop from `i = 0 : reps[tid]`, storing `tid` at `cumulative_reps[tid]+i`.

This would work, but could end up doing most of the work in serial, and defeating the point of using CUDA.

I'm wondering if there's a combination of thrust iterators and algorithms to concisely produce the integer list?
Alternatively, a better approach than the one I outlined, even without thrust, would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this purely with thrust, using an approach similar to yours.

1. Do a prefix sum on the input to determine size of result for step 2, and scatter indices for step 3
2. Create an output vector to hold the result
3. scatter ones to the appropriate locations in the output vector, given by the indices from step 1
4. do a prefix sum on the output vector.

Note that this method would have to be modified if the input reps vector is allowed to contain values of 0.

Here's a worked example:

```
$ cat t404.cu
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

  int host_reps[] = {3, 2, 5, 1};
  int ds = sizeof(host_reps)/sizeof(int);
  thrust::device_vector<int> reps(host_reps, host_reps+ds);
  thrust::inclusive_scan(reps.begin(), reps.end(), reps.begin());
  thrust::device_vector<int> result(reps[reps.size()-1]);
  thrust::copy_n(thrust::constant_iterator<int>(1), reps.size()-1, thrust::make_permutation_iterator(result.begin(), reps.begin()));
  thrust::inclusive_scan(result.begin(), result.end(), result.begin());
  thrust::copy_n(result.begin(), result.size(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t404 t404.cu
$ ./t404
0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,
$
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you this is great, and in answer to your last point, zeros are not allowed in the reps array.

Comment: There was a bug in my posted code.  I have fixed it now.